# How to access items metadata in Stripe checkout session

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stripe-payments

When I create a Checkout session, I am creating prices on the fly with `price_data` and `product_data` properties. For each item, I am putting metadata in the `product_data.metadata` property.

After payment is successfully finished, I fetch the session data in order to display Payment Successful page to the customer. But for some reason, metadata of the items are empty. Metadata of the items are present when I check it in the Dashboard, but they are empty when I fetch it with API.

I tried to fetch whole session data with expanded `line_items` property:

```js
const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.retrieve(session_id, { expand: ['line_items'] });
```

And I also tried to fetch the items directly:

```js
const line_items = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(session_id);
```

In both scenarios, metadata of each item is empty.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When creating the items on the fly, metadata ends up in the **product** property, and not in the **price** property.

So I solved the issue with expanding the items with product data:

```js
const line_items = await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(session_id, {
  expand: ['data.price.product'],
});
```

The response have the metadata inside `product` property.

Comment: You've saved my sanity,  after almost  a week of trying, I don't know why you post never came up after all the searches I did, I happened to find it  after scrolling for a while

Comment: whew :) very thx..