# Stripe-node: metadata empty when retrieving a Checkout Session's line items

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, stripe-payments

I've created a stripe checkout session where I'm passing the products I receive from the request's body in **line_items property**. In the **product_data** of each product I added a **metadata that contains the product's id**.

```
try {
        const cart: ICart[] = req.body.cart;
        const accountEmail: string = req.body.account;
        const tax: number = req.body.tax;
        const discountId: string = req.body.discount; 

        const cartItems: Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams.LineItem[] =
            cart.map((item): Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams.LineItem => {
                return {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: "mad",
                        product_data: {
                            name: item?.name,
                            description: item?.description,
                            images: item?.images,
                            metadata: { id: item?._id },
                        },
                        unit_amount: item?.amount * 100,
                    },
                    quantity: item?.quantity,
                };
            });

        // create the checkout session
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            currency: "mad",
            ui_mode: "hosted",
            line_items: [
                ...(cartItems as Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateParams.LineItem[]),
            ],
            billing_address_collection: "required",
            mode: "payment",
            customer_email: accountEmail,
            metadata: {
                email: accountEmail,
                tax: tax,
                discount: discountId,
            },
            success_url: `${env.APP_URL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
            cancel_url: `${env.APP_URL}/success?session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
        });
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            session,
            clientSecret: session.client_secret,
        });
} catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
}
```

Then I created a **webhook** that listens to the **checkout.session.completed event type**, where I **retrieve the line_items of that particular checkout session**, for the purpose of creating an **order document (beacause I'am working with mongoose)** and save it in my database, but the problem is: **I can't find the id I defined in each product's metadata**.

```
// in the webhook's swith case
// retrieving the line items
case "checkout.session.completed":
      const checkoutSessionCompleted = event.data.object;
          
      // Retrieve the session's line items
      const lineItems = (await stripe.checkout.sessions.listLineItems(checkoutSessionCompleted.id)).data.map((item) => {
      return {
              _id: item.price?.metadata?.id, // returns undefined
              quantity: item.quantity, // returns the quantity
             }
         });
```

Here's the link to stripe api docs if you need proof:
[stripe-api docs retrieve line_items](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/line_items)

Thanks,

Comment: I'm literally stuck here too, for a couple days now, I've searched everywhere, no help, I think at this point, I might just create the order in the checkout endpoint, then save in database, then pass the orderId directly in the "create" metadata, then in the webhook, I retrieve the orderId and fetch and update the order with new information, this is gonna be my last resort if I don't find a solution in a few more days

Answer (score 1):

You assigned the metadata on the product object, but you are trying to retrieve them from a different price object, which doesn't have metadata set.

You should retrieve the [product](https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoiceitems/object#invoiceitem_object-price-product) from the the invoice item's price object, and so that you can get its metadata.

Comment: Why? Didn't I set the metadata in the product_data of the line_items concerning the checkout session, not in the invoice.
Also, if It's in the invoice like you said sir, there's no way to retrieve the invoice from the checkoutSessionCompleted object.
Can you provide me with some example code please?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell by seeing your code, you have assigned the id in cartItems/price_data/product_data/metadata which is passed as line_items. However, you are trying to retrieve the line_items(cartItems)/price(price_data)/metadata which has not been assigned.
The Id you are searching for is assigned in line_items(cartItems)/price(price_data)/product_data(maybe some alias couldn't find the value in documentation)/metadata

Comment: I understand what your saying, if you can take a look at the link I provided to the stripe api docs, the object returned from retrieving the line_items has the following structure:
=> line_items/data(array of items)/price/metadata
It's certainly different from when you declare it at first.

Comment: Then you might want to check a couple of things if the line_items/price contains a description and image or not. If it exists, then the product_data object is opened in price in checkout. Then check if your price/nickname is empty or not. If it is empty/null/undefined it means that the value was not assigned in product_data. Then lastly check if the id is being populated by items?.id or not.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer, here https://stackoverflow.com/a/71352601/17971158, we have the ability to expand the line items when we retrieve them